# heroku run knex migrate:latest errors: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection and knex migrate Error: self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I have a NodeJS application running on Heroku with a Heroku Postgres database.

Right now (`pg@^7.18.2` & `knex@^0.21.14`), when I run `heroku run knex migrate:latest -a my-awesome-app` I get the following error:

```
KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:348:26)
    at async listCompleted (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/migration-list-resolver.js:12:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Migrator.latest (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/Migrator.js:64:29)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:172:32)
```

I Googled and found many people saying the solution was to update to `pg@^8`, so I did that (upgraded both `pg` & `knex` to their latest stable versions) but I now got a different error. This time the error is:

```
heroku run knex migrate Error: self signed certificate
```

So I Googled the new error, and people were saying the solution was to add `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },` to the Knex config object, but I did that too, and I still got the "self sign certificate" error.

I even tried the [suggestions here](https://www.gaticonsulting.com/blog/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain/), but still no luck, the error remained.

Some answers were suggesting I should go back to version `pg@^7` to overcome the certificate error, but in my case I just go back to the timeout acquiring a connection error.

I'm stuck between two errors and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you have the cert/key/ca for the connection?

Comment: No, do I need one? If yes, how do I go about obtaining one.

Comment: Not sure about heroku.. possibly can't [according to this](https://help.heroku.com/3DELT3RK/why-can-t-my-third-party-utility-connect-to-heroku-postgres-with-ssl). Although what do you configure to connect from your heroku app? (not using the `knex` cli)

Comment: Could you share your knexfile please? I'm wondering if you have your `ssl` block in the wrong place, or if there's something else Heroku-specific going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your node version, probably you're using new version of node js and knex is having some problems with node v14. Try to downgrade it to v12 .

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for posterity if anyone comes across this. The syntax I used for Heroku postgres that I didn't see anywhere else is:

```
// knexfile.js 
module.exports = {
  
  // dev environment here...
  
  production: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + "/db/migrations",
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: __dirname + "/db/seeds",
    },
  },
};
```

[my medium article which goes through the various docs and links](https://dpletzke.medium.com/configuring-free-heroku-node-postgresql-hosting-with-knex-b0e97a05c6af)